# Catching AFJSONRequestOperation error when posting JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, afnetworking

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the JSON that's being sent by my app to my web API as every time it would send the message it would always go through the "failure" block of the command. But when I try to test the web API on my local it does work and it does post so my guess is there's something wrong with the JSON being sent when I'm creating the message. Here's my code:

```
+ (NSArray *)getKeysFighterVM{
    NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Id",
                            @"EventId", 
                            @"RegistrationId",
                            @"FirstName",
                            @"LastName", nil];
    return keys;
}


-(void)checkInFighterWCFToBracketId:(NSNumber *)bracketId :(void(^)(bool success, NSError *error, id JSON)) block{

    NSArray *requestKeys = [Fighter getWCFKeysFighterVM];
    NSArray *requestValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.Id stringValue]],
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.eventId stringValue]],
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.regId stringValue]],
                              [NSNull null],
                              [NSNull null],
                              nil];

    NSDictionary *jsonRequestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:requestValues forKeys:requestKeys];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"THISWHEREMYAPIURLRESIDES"];


    AFHTTPClient *httpclient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    httpclient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpclient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:jsonRequestDictionary];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS JSON %@", JSON);
        block(YES, nil, JSON);
    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
        JSON = [request HTTPBody];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
        NSLog(@"FAILURE ERROR JSON %@", jsonDict);
        NSArray *jsonarray = (NSArray *)JSON;


        NSLog(@"----FAILURE ERROR array %@", jsonarray);


        NSLog(@"FAILURE ERROR USErInfo %@", [error userInfo]);
        block(NO, error, JSON);
    }];

    [operation start];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];
}
```

So I tried returning what it looks like but comes back like these:

> ----FAILURE ERROR array <7b225573 65724964 223a2238 222c2242 69727468 44617465 223a6e75 6c6c2c22 41636164 656d794e 616d6522 3a6e756c
>   6c2c2246 69727374 4e616d65 223a6e75 6c6c2c22 4c617374 4e616d65
>   223a6e75 6c6c2c22 4576656e 74496422 3a223522 2c224576 656e7446
>   69676874 65725265 67697374 72617469 6f6e4964 223a2235 227d>

Comment: If the "failure" block is being reached then you should log the `error` value.

Comment: Yes, I got that already and the thing that's causing the error is that it won't recognize the set of data coming from the json sent. I'm using .Net webapi, so it's basically accepting a Model class on the method of the api, which IF null means the json wasn't formatted correctly.

Comment: The "array" you are logging is actually the NSData for a string that starts with `{UsAH1@":"8",`.

Comment: I recommend using a tool like "Charles" and look at your request from using web and using your app, find the difference and then attack that

Comment: Is charles the same as fiddler but for ios?